# Finding function with discontinuity at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous everywhere except $x = 0$. The only example that comes to mind is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, but this isn't even a candidate, I think, because it is undefined at $x = 0$, so I can't really talk about "continuity" at $x = 0$. Another option is a function with a jump discontinuity at $x = 0$: something like $f(x) = x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$. Then I can take a sequence of points, either from above or below, converging to $0$, but not to $f(0)$.

Is this incorrect? Is there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: There are tons of functions like this. $\operatorname{sgn}$ and the Heaviside step are good examples.

Comment: My first thought was to modify your $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ function to: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0,\ $ $f(x) = 0\ $ for $\ x = 0.$ Also, it's not clear what you're actually asking, as K. defaoite says, there are tons of functions which are discontinuous at just one point. Are you asking for a specific type of discontinuity? If so, this may be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities

Answer (score 1):

The "jump discontinuity" approach is very common.
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$
is indeed not defined at $0$, so it is not an example of the desired function.

The canonical example is called a $\delta$ function, which there are two (Dirac and Kronecker). In a set-theoretic application, the Kronkecker delta function is also called an indicator function.

Take
$$
\delta_a(x) =  \begin{cases}1 & x = a \\ 0 &  x \neq a\end{cases}
$$

In topology, the "[topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve)" can be extended onto all of $\mathbb R$ by

$$
T(x) = \begin{cases} \sin\left( \frac \pi x\right) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
$T$ has some interesting topological properties when restricted to $(0,1]$.

Answer (score -2):

What about

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}x,&x\neq0\\{}\\-4,&x=0\end{cases}\;\;\;?$$

Comment: I touch your post by accident, then I put it back. Sorry.